# Alert ou Popup javascript após validação de formulário no SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, sharepoint, alert

Esta é a minha primeira participação, por favor, desculpe os erros de iniciante.

Amigos, preciso fazer um alert ou um popup javascript ou Jquery para utilizar em formulário do sharepoint. Preciso que ele me dê uma mensagem se não passar na validação dos campos ou mensagem de cadastrado com sucesso se estiver tudo ok com o preenchimento.

Por favor, me ajudem.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Bem vindo.
Fiz um código simples para te mostrar uma idéia bem tranquila de ser implementada em qualquer código.
Link do codepen: [Exemplo - CodePen](https://codepen.io/Buuu/pen/qmbxXq)

Na parte HTML, o local do texto você pode mudar por javascript ou até mesmo algo fixo.

No javascript/Jquery você pode ver que tenho uma situação que envolve um boolean, se tal situação, mostra a div destacada com a mensagem. Se falso, não mostra nada.

Espero ter ajudado